# Parent status not changed if all childs status changed and vice-versa in Kanban board in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs-2015, kanban

If I drag a parent (say Feature) in Kanban board (say from Open Status to closed Status), then the status of its childs (say User stories) is not changed.

Similarly if I drag all childs (say User Stories) in Kanban board (say from Open Status to closed Status), then the status of its parent (say Feature) is not changed.

**Is this the expected behavior? Please throw some light?**

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct phenomenon for now. You can use some [third-party extension](http://www.tfsasap.com/) to achieve this for a workaround.

And there has been a feature request in UserVoice, you can also vote up for it:

> **Automatic State Transition based on linked Work Item State**
>   https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2830827-automatic-state-transition-based-on-linked-work-it